# Why does sha1 give me different hash if data is echoed from file instead of directly on command line?

Tags: encryption, sha1

I am trying to figure out why I am not getting the same hash when running a string through the `sha1` algorithm.

Please consider these results:

```
echo moosecodes | shasum
538f5d940a8f1aeabde1d5c6da4ebae1230ba5da  -

echo -n moosecodes | shasum  
c09129372713d1c7005f4aa1d50bf598912c473a  -
```

**temp.txt** contains the string `moosecodes` with no new line, but the hash is different when the string is echoed from a file:

```
echo temp.txt | shasum
c3ec5f2c30a4198dc4e0323101441da0bcdd2aa9  -

echo -n temp.txt | shasum
45ebed19db9cfb3cea503d6b62a50ffe6b30247c  -
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? At first I thought it had to do with the fact that the file has meta-data attached to it, but in this case I am just echo-ing its contents to the hasher, so wouldn't it be the same as the first two examples I show above?

Comment: what do you get when you run just `echo temp.txt` from the shell? Now do you see?

Comment: I am not a smart man.... lol... i see exactly what you mean now! thanks, @JamesKPolk!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running`echo temp.txt | shasum`, not `cat temp.txt | shasum` or `shasum < temp.txt`. Rather than testing the shasum of the content of the file `temp.txt`, you are accidentally taking the `shasum` of the string "temp.txt".

```sh
# Your first example
$ echo moosecodes | shasum
538f5d940a8f1aeabde1d5c6da4ebae1230ba5da *-
$ echo -n moosecodes | shasum
c09129372713d1c7005f4aa1d50bf598912c473a *-

# Now prepare the file...
$ echo -n moosecodes > temp.txt

# But accidentally take the shasum of the string "temp.txt",
# with or without the newline.
$ echo temp.txt | shasum
c3ec5f2c30a4198dc4e0323101441da0bcdd2aa9 *-
$ echo -n temp.txt | shasum
45ebed19db9cfb3cea503d6b62a50ffe6b30247c *-

# However, you can use the "cat" command to pipe the text...
$ cat temp.txt | shasum
c09129372713d1c7005f4aa1d50bf598912c473a *-
# Or properly redirect from a file using < ...
$ shasum < temp.txt
c09129372713d1c7005f4aa1d50bf598912c473a *-
# Or even just pass the filename into shasum directly.
$ shasum temp.txt
c09129372713d1c7005f4aa1d50bf598912c473a *temp.txt
```

Comment: I feel incredibly stupid right now.  but thanks for the explanation! it makes sense!!